# Print to console from application extension

Tags: ios, console, swift, ios8, ios-app-extension

I've been playing around with the new custom keyboard application extension API in iOS 8, using Swift as my language of choice. One thing I've noticed, however, is that `println` doesn't seem to ever print any output to the console, presumably because those statements are being executed in an application extension rather than the containing app. Has anyone found a way to print statements to the console from within an application extension?

Comment: Not sure about from an extension, but you can always try good old fashioned NSLog or make a logging breakpoint in Xcode.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to debug iOS 8 extensions with NSLog?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24031612/how-to-debug-ios-8-extensions-with-nslog)

Comment: I'm having trouble here too even with NSLog.  I can step through my extension using the debugger on the simulator fine, but no NSLog messages ever show on the console.  I've also tried running the extension and then connecting the debugger to the extension process, but still nothing on the console.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your most reliable choice is to use `NSLog` for debugging purposes, but `println` might actually be working in this case. You just need to attach the Xcode debugger to the extension itself.

In my experience, it's a rather buggy process. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24050325/1849664) has more info on the subject. In short, you need to change the target in the Run drop down to your extension, then after you click run you should get a list of things you can run it *in*.

Answer (score 8):

As of iOS 10, extensions don't log to console by default. To enable console logging for your extension:

- Select your extension target in the Xcode target popup
- Select Product menu > Scheme > Edit Scheme (or Cmd <)
- In the Run phase under environment variables, add name:`OS_ACTIVITY_MODE` value: `disable`

Comment: doesn't work for me, I still don't see neither prints nor NSLog's. Could you please let me know which other options I probably need to turn on?

Comment: I'd like to add it doesn't work if I attach the debugger but if I run it directly with the right scheme target it works.