# Can't execute code with new Share Extension target

Tags: ios8, xcode6, ios-app-extension

So I just created an app share extension target. It shows up fine in other apps such as safari. When I click share, my app shows up in the list of sharing options.

However, I can't get any of the default SLComposeServiceViewController methods to be called. Clicking post does not run the didSelectPost method. I've set break points in all the default methods and none are hit.

Is there anything I have to do to hookup this new target?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to debug iOS 8 extensions with NSLog?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24031612/how-to-debug-ios-8-extensions-with-nslog)

Comment: Check out, http://stackoverflow.com/a/24056113/250190