# Can't view NSLog messages for App Extensions in iOS8

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8, ios-app-extension

I have tried everything in this thread:
[How to debug iOS 8 extensions with NSLog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24031612/how-to-debug-ios-8-extensions-with-nslog)

And I am still unable to view NSLog messages for my app extension in Beta 5 & XCode Beta 5.

Would someone mind posting a step by step?

Here's what I've tried:

- Running companion app - doesn't automatically attach when extension
  is loaded (stays at 'Waiting to attach')
- Running companion app, then attaching manually by typing in extension name
- Attaching manually by running extension scheme and choosing another app (I've tried Safari, my companion app, others in this scenario)
- Tried all of this on device and in simulator

In earlier beta's you could toggle between the main target an the extension here, but not anymore (why!?):

[image]

No luck for any of them. Super frustrated because I've got to the point where I can't seem to debug anything. If anyone can help I'd appreciate it!

Comment: Some thing is currently happening with me, very weird... when I run in simulator NSLog starts workings magically though!

Comment: Aha! http://stackoverflow.com/a/25225394/2057171

Answer (score 1):

For me the problem was in the NSLog window I had the simulator selected instead of my actually device... Click where I click in image below to reveal all options then select your device. Now launch your app extension inside your app itself.

[image]