# AFNetworking sometimes not working on iOS 8 & 9 at real device

Tags: ios, afnetworking-2

I develop app for iOS8 & iOS9.
Recently I came the situations that HTTP networking cannot access Rails server at real iOS8 & iOS9 devices. This was often happened iOS9 but iOS8 was sometimes. This problem is not consistency, sometimes first network access is OK, but third or fourth access can not work. the The simulators can always access server.
Of corse I know ATS and I set what all http access is OK.

Environmental
Xcode 7.1.1
CocoaPods 0.39.0
AFNerworking(use AFHTTPSessionManager) 2.6.1
real device iPhone5S iOS8.2
real device iPhone6 iOS9.1

Error Log
`Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001`
I think that there may be other errors, but I forgot it.

If anyone know the answer, please tell me.

Comment: Unless you show some codes, I am guessing that your mobile devices has bad network connections. Are they connected to same network(Wi-Fi) or mobile data(3G/4G)? Fyi, I am using AFNetworking in my projects without any problems so far.

Comment: I use same Wi-Fi network and network connection is OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Apple's [CFNetwork error documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Networking/Reference/CFNetworkErrors/index.html#//apple_ref/c/econst/kCFURLErrorTimedOut) the "-1001" value actually stands for:

```
 kCFURLErrorTimedOut  = -1001
```

So easy enough the main problem here is your internet speed and quality, especially when you use a mobile device in a poor signal situation. My suggestion would be to update to the latest version of AFNetworking from the official [GitHub](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) project page and test again using also a Wi-Fi connection if the problem appears again.

If you keep facing this issue please post some code if you can so we can see what's wrong. By the way, have you changed the network timeout timer? Is so, reset it to the default value, a short value could cause this.

Comment: Thank you answer. I upgrade AFNetworking 2.6.1 to 2.6.3 and real devices can access server. But, I met another problem what share extension can not debug.[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33870693/ios9-share-extension-can-not-debug-on-xcode)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use NSURLSession. I think you can do everything with it. Unfortunately I haven't used AFNetworking for a long time, so I dk if it works.

Comment: I use many AFNetworking functions. So, I think I could not make all these functions by myself.