# "Waiting to attach" issue with Today Extensions

Tags: ios, xcode, build, widget, today-extension

I've got a serious issue and can't figure out where is the problem !
First this question has already been answered in two other threads : 
[iOS 8 beta 5 Today view extension (widget) stuck at Waiting to Attach](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25397083/4662531)

BUT, my problem is different : I've got 10 widgets, and they all work fine. I can debug them without any problems, both on my device and simulator. But starting from the eleventh, my today Extensions stay stuck on "Waiting to attach" when I try to debug them on my device (on the simulator it works fine). 
I have tried to clean the project, delete the target (which represent de widget), restart both computer and device, but the wall is still here ...
Even the default Today Extension "Hello word" stay stuck.

So if anyone has an idea, it would be great, because this issue is ruining my day, grrr.
Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just find the answer after a day of research... pfff so many time wasted for nothing !

I've update Xcode yesterday, my widgets deployment target were on 8.1, and those after the update are on 8.2... my iphone is a 8.1. 
So when you update your Xcode, it will take the latest version of iOS, just make sure it matches your iPhone version, otherwise it will never show up on your phone ;)

Thanks anyway!

Comment: also make sure the simulator you are deploying to is compatible with your deployment targets because that could happen...