# Can't debug iOS 8 App Extension

Tags: ios, xcode6, breakpoints, ios-app-extension

I'm trying to debug the sample Action App Extension provided on Xcode 6 (6A313).
Even though the app runs flawlessly, I can't see any NSLog messages on the [Debug Area](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/recipes/xcode_help-debugger/articles/about_debug_area.html) neither Xcode will stop on my break points.

Things I've tried:

- I've tried uninstalling Xcode 6, re-downloading it from the Mac Store and installing again with no success.
- I've also tried to go through *Debug -> Attach to Process -> By Process Identifier (PID) or Name...* but the Status Bar shows "Waiting for -*bundle id*- to launch" when it is already running.
- Tried different devices.
- Tried running on the simulator, but my App Extension won't show on the App Extensions list (it is not present in the "more" list also).
- I've checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24031612/how-to-debug-ios-8-extensions-with-nslog) answer also, which didn't help me.

I've ran out of ideas on what to do :)

Comment: We've had a lot of issues trying to debug today extensions. One thing that helped is using NSLogger from GitHub to log to a Mac via WiFi instead of relying on Xcode.

Comment: @EricS Gonna give that a shot

Answer (score 4):

When you added the Application Extension target Xcode should have added also a new Scheme for the Extension (or you can create one in 'Manage Schemes...').
If this happened you just have to change the Active Scheme, on the very left of the drop down with which you choose the device/os of the simulator, and run.

[image: Selecting the extension active scheme]

If you change the Active Scheme to the Widget one, then breakpoint and NSLog works, at least for me.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but yes, I'm definetely running the App Extesion scheme. I tried removing the scheme and manually creating another one, again with no luck.

Comment: We went back to the app extension after a while and with current version of Xcode (7.2) we didn't have any problems debugging and logging