# XCode 6.1.1 - Today extension debug

Tags: xcode, ios8-extension, ios8-today-widget

I have installed new XCode and now I have problem debugging my todays extension (in simulator or device - not working in both of them). Steps from Apple documentation are not working, extension is always hanging on "Waiting to attach". I have also tried this: [How to debug iOS 8 extensions with NSLog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24031612/how-to-debug-ios-8-extensions-with-nslog), but also with no luck.

Comment: Does the whole process fail, or does the extension load while Xcode sits there thinking it needs to keep waiting?

Comment: It loads and XCode is thinking that it needs to wait.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found some kind of a solution for device.

- Before running and extension, I lock my device to lock screen
- Run extension
- Attach it to today process
- Do not unlock device, just scroll down extension sceen It should attach to XCode

For me this worked in 80% of cases, If not, lock device again and wait a little :-), then try again

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and in my case it was because I had configured Xcode to use a custom location for its "derived data" folder. Custom locations are supported, but a bug currently means that using one breaks debugging with app extensions. Xcode knows where your breakpoints are but thinks it hasn't loaded any code that matches them yet.

For me the fix was to go to Xcode preferences --> Locations, and set the "derived data" location to "default".