# Keyboard Extensions Xcode 6.3?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-app-extension

Everything was working perfectly when debugging my keyboard on Xcode 6.2 running iOS 8.2. After updating to Xcode 6.3 and iOS 8.3, I seem to be having difficulty getting the debugger to work. Has anyone experience similar problems? I've tried cleaning my build, uninstalling/installing my app, but nothing seems to work.

What happens is I build and run, and when I switch between keyboards to get to mine it just never pops up, instead it jumps to the default one. Upon ending the task, and doing it again it works perfectly, just not when I'm attempting to debug.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I'm consistently seeing the same issue and it's making development very difficult.

Comment: @fisch2 Unfortunately I haven't. But if I do I'll update this post.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the information from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24031612/how-to-debug-ios-8-extensions-with-nslog) is a bit outdated, but it was useful to me.  I am still convinced that extension debugging on devices is 90% broken with XCode 6.3.2 and iOS 8.3.  I've been debugging successfully from the simulator, though, and occasionally I'll get the device process to attach correctly from within XCode, but more often than not it just quits on me.