# I can't debug TodayExtension in Xcode Version 7.2 (7C68)

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7, today-extension

I'm developing a TodayExtension for an iPhone app but I'm not able to debug the extension.

I have added some breakpoints in my TodayExtension View Controller but it doesn't stop neither print NSLog().

When I'm trying to debug, I get a crash before it starts to debug.

Any idea?

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik that's no right. Example: http://www.amaniphoneblog.com/2014/10/debug-extensions-for-ios-8-in-xcode.html

Comment: sry bro when I developed the extension on that time I cant find the solution that the reason I added that , @Eni -- see this link it helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24031612/how-to-debug-ios-8-extensions-with-nslog

Comment: Thanks! It solves it!

Comment: welcome bro... happy to hear this...

Comment: Mmmm it runs only sometimes...

Comment: oh ice, try this http://easynativeextensions.com/how-to-debug-your-ios-extension/