# App Extension does not debug properly

Tags: ios, debugging, ios-app-extension

I am creating a Today App extension.  In Xcode, I specify the scheme to launch the Extension target and place a breakpoint in viewDidLoad.  The debugger will stop at the breakpoint the first time, but then not again for many launches.  Some random things, like clearing the logs from the device or making sure the Today/Notification screen is closed before relaunching seem to have some effect on the frequency with which it successfully hits the breakpoint but hardly enough to make development practical.  I am about at the point of filing a bug report so is there any knowledge about this in the development community?  I am building to an iphone 6s running ios9.

Comment: Are you sure you're attaching the debugger to the right process? It's not so easy to do... You don't give any evidence, in your question, that you have read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24031612/how-to-debug-ios-8-extensions-with-nslog for example.

Comment: I am simply selecting the scheme that targets the app extension.  The evidence is that the breakpoint is triggered sometimes and not others.  It is clearly set up correctly but having random behavior for whatever reason.  Yes, I have read what I can surmise as everything on stack concerning debugging extensions.  When I go to attach debugger to process it states it is "already debugging [process]", while 9/10 times it hangs in a paused state while saying "waiting to attach to process" in the left pane of xcode..